# Calculation of the limit $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n^2x(1-x)^n, x \in [0,1]$ and the supremum

Tags: limits

How can I find this limit:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} n^2x(1-x)^n, x \in [0,1]$$

Do I have to use the L'Hospital rule? If so, do I have to differentiate with respect to $n$ or to $x$ ?

**EDIT:**

I also tried to find the supremum of $n^2x(1-x)^n$..I found that $f(x)=n^2x(1-x)^n$ achieves its maximum at the point $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and that $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} n^2x(1-x)^n=\frac{n}{e} \to +\infty$

Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: With respect to $n$. Note $x=0$ or $x=1$ are trivial cases, and don't require anything fancy.

Comment: Since $1-x^2<0,\forall x\in(0,1)$;

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2x(1-x)^n=\lim\limits_{n\to 0} n^2\exp(n\ln(1-x^2))=0$, $\forall x\in(0,1)$ 

for $x\in\{0,1\}$ it should be clear.

Comment: You can factor out $x$ and note that $1-x$ is a positive constant $<1$ (trivial limit cases $0$ and $1$ handled separately). Your limit is a product of a power by a negative exponential, $n^2e^{-pn}$. The latter are known to decrease faster than any power.

Comment: Your derivation of the maximum is correct. It simply shows that the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: @Frédéric Nice,thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Hmm... if I fill in $x=\frac 1{n+1}$ I do not get $\frac n e$...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the trivial cases pointed out by David Mitra, you can `pull out' $x$ out of the limit -it's a constant and look at $Lf = \log f(x)$.
$$
Lf = 2 \log x +n \log(1-x)
$$
Clearly the expression is $O(n)$, and $\log(1-x)<0$, so $Lf \to -\infty.$ Exponentiating it back, you get the limit of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

This limit is always zero, there are two cases:

1)$x=0$-it's obvious.

2)$x \neq 0$, then the limit is zero, because $1-x <1$ and exponential function decrease faster than polynomial $n^2$

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to apply L'hospital.

Let $x \neq 0$ or $1$ (trivial cases). Define $x_n=n^{2}x(1-x)^n$. We have

$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}(1-x)x_n 
$$

implying ($x\in $(0,1)) that there is a value of $n$ after which the $x_{n+1}<x_n$. Furthermore $x_n>0$, hence it converges to $L$. Taking the limit on both sides of the equation we get

$$
L=(1-x)L
$$
leading to $L=0$.